# doctrine 2, how do get data from the inverse side (many to one)

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, entry and comments.

comments:

```
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="\Entities\Blog\CommentRepository")
 * @Table(name="blog_comment")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Comment extends \Entities\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entry", inversedBy="comments")
     * @JoinColumn(name="entry_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $entry;

    /** @Column(name="approved", type="string", length=255) */
    protected $approved;

    /** @Column(name="title", type="string", length=255) */
    protected $title;

    /** @Column(name="content", type="text") */
    protected $content;

    /** @Column(name="pub_date", type="datetime") */
    protected $pub_date;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $created_at;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $updated_at;

    /** @PreUpdate */
    public function updated()
    {
        $this->updated_at = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->created_at = $this->updated_at = new \DateTime("now");
    }
}

class CommentRepository extends \Entities\PaginatedRepository
{
    protected $_entityClassName = 'Entities\Blog\Comment';
}
```

and entry:

```
<?php
namespace Entities\Blog;

/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="\Entities\Blog\EntryRepository")
 * @Table(name="blog_entry")
 * @HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Entry extends \Entities\AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /** @Column(name="permalink", type="string", length=255) */
    protected $permalink;

    /** @Column(name="title", type="string", length=255) */
    protected $title;

    /** @Column(name="pub_date", type="datetime") */
    protected $pub_date;

    /** @Column(name="content", type="text") */
    protected $content;

    /** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="entry") */
    protected $comments;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $created_at;

    /** @Column(type="datetime") */
    private $updated_at;

    /** @PreUpdate */
    public function updated()
    {
        $this->updated_at = new \DateTime("now");
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->comments = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

I can get the collection of all comments belonging to each entry via:

```
foreach ($comments as $comment){
   $comment-$commentId;
}
```

but how can I get the entry information from the comments side. for example, I would like to get the entry id from a specific comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you create a `@OneToMany` relation, you create a `Collection` of proxy objects in class on "One"-side of relation, and single proxy object in class on "Many"-side of relation. Proxy classes are automatically generated by Doctrine2 from your mapping information.

To allow Doctrine2 filling proxy object with real data from DB it's important to declare it `protected` or `private`. I'm not sure about that, but seems like Doctrine tracks down any requests to proxy objects inside your entity class and ensures that proxies are populated before first usage.

To access the associated object you have to define accessor function in your `Comment` class:

```
class Comment extends \Entities\AbstractEntity{
    /** other definitions */

    function getEntity(){
        return $this->entity;
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
$comment = $em->find("Entities\Comment",1);
$entity = $comment->getEntity();
```

Doctrine2 will automatically populate `$comment->entity` proxy with actual `Entity` object.

See ["Workin with Objects" chapter of Doctrine documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html) and ["Can you explain me what is a Proxy in Doctrine 2?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923817/can-you-explain-me-what-is-a-proxy-in-doctrine-2)  on details of proxies.

Comment: so in my case, it would be:  function getEntity(){
        return $this->entry;     ?

Comment: doesnt work on the many side...   should be straight forward as you would want to access the related data...

Comment: I'll post you some code samples, I have them on my home computer.