# Should I clear/warm cache after doctrine migrations?

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine, capifony

I would like to know about how symfony2 console commands `cache:clear` and `cache:warmup` works in regards to changes in doctrine entities.

I've read this http://blog.whiteoctober.co.uk/2014/02/25/symfony2-cache-warmup-explained/ and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17787070/779320. There it is stated that symfony2 warm-up generates Doctrine proxies.

Thing is, I frequently have a situation after application deploy using capifony where I must run doctrine migrations. After that I always run `cache:clear` and `cache:warmup`.

According to the links above (if I understand correctly), if there is any entity addition/deletion, I should run `cache:warmup`. But what if there is only entity's fields changes. Should I run both `cache:clear` and `cache:warmup` commands necessary to be run or just one? Or, which one is necessary? Or, not at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrations are responsible for persistence layer only. It has nothing to do with EntityProxies, it only makes `Database` in sync with `Model` - that's all.

In production, during deployment, you probably run `git pull` and `composer install`, which clears the cache, so migrations shoud run just after that.

Reason - after `composer install` your new code and Model itself is ready to use new fields/entities, but the Database still falls behind, so migrations keeps it in sync.

Comment: Sounds logical. Thanks!