# symfony3 strange proxy behaviour

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working with Symfony3, and at one point I need to get the class name from an entity object.

I have two tables: role and tier.  Both have only two fields: id and name.  If I do a query to get these entities, one comes back as a regular entity (as is expected), but the other comes back as a proxy, and I can't understand why.

Tier **is** a foreign key and belongs to another table, but in this instance I'm only getting the tiers, so I don't see why this should matter.

Can anyone explain how or if there is anything I can do in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Its normal that you have proxy. Doctrine use the lazy loading to load entities. I advice you to read this answer:

> [stackoverflow.com/a/17787070/2377164](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17787070/2377164)

Anyway you should be able to use your "proxy" as an entity. Doctrine will load the data you need when you'll try to get some properties

Comment: I understand that proxies themselves are fine, my question is why I'm receiving one in one case, but not the other.

More specifically, I am getting an autoload error when I try to instantiate the proxy (new Proxy\__CG__\.......()).  Could this be a permissions issue?