# Symfony Doctrine entities disable Proxy (while Xdebugging)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, proxy-classes

Whenever I use Xdebug to debug variables I see alot of `Proxies\__CG__\` classes instead of my real classes. Is there any way to disable these? I want to eager load everything instead of lazy loading.

These Proxy (entity) classes have every property null, only the `id` is filled. This is not nice when using Xdebug to debug values from variables.

When I'm using the 'Evaluate Expression' tool, I can do `$entity->getSomeEntity()->getName();` and it's not empty (lazy loading?). But without evaluating the expression, the value is null.

Tried to change [Doctrine configuration](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#auto-generating-proxy-classes-optional) `auto_generate_proxy_classes` to `0` but weirdly this doesn't seem to change a thing.

Comment: AFAIK the proxy classes will always be used, the setting `auto_generate_proxy_classes` just determines if they will be generated on runtime or not.  Mybe this helps understanding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923817/what-is-a-proxy-in-doctrine-2?rq=1

Comment: > $entity->getSomeEntity()->getName(); and it's not empty (lazy loading?).
that's the point of lazy loading :)
You could change your relations to `fetch="EAGER"` but **it could cause** massive performance drop!